# Setting underline span in edittext without removing autosuggest

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, autosuggest, spannablestring

I didn't expect this to be a problem but I cant simply underline words in my edittext because of the underline in softkeyboard's autosuggest feature which automatically underlines a selected word .However I still want to keep the feature while applying underlines.

In edittext:

[image: By default a selected word is automatically underlined]

By default a selected word is automatically underlined then when space is clicked the underline is removed so when I apply underline span via a button then hit space it gets removed.

Applying underlinespan:-

```
SpannableString word = new SpannableString(noteview.getText());

word.setSpan((new UnderlineSpan()), 0, word.length(), 0);

edittext.setText(word);
```

This code works fine if the word isn't selected so I tried changing selection before spanning but still it didn't workout.Is there maybe a workaround to remove the auto-suggest underline?.

Comment: Have you textAllCaps true in your textview? May be its the default property of button. set it to false and try again.

Comment: No I don't have textAllCaps .

Comment: add it with false value

Comment: It didn't workout and am using an edittext.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I added `edittext.clearComposingText();` before setting the span it doesn't remove the underline however removes the underline's effect on span